# Exporting / Importing trees created with python anytree 2.4.3 library

Tags: python, tree, python-3.6, anytree

I create a tree with anytree library. I want to be able to modify it, then export - save it to disk, and import it back with the modifications. For instance, the example tree:

```
udo = Node("Udo")
marc = Node("Marc", parent=udo)
lian = Node("Lian", parent=marc)
dan = Node("Dan", parent=udo)
jet = Node("Jet", parent=dan)
jan = Node("Jan", parent=dan)
joe = Node("Joe", parent=dan)

Udo
├── Marc
│   └── Lian
└── Dan
    ├── Jet
    ├── Jan
    └── Joe
```

I can modify it, for instance cutting Dan off and adding a children to Marc

```
dan.parent = None 
bonny = Node ("Bonny", parent = marc)

Udo
└── Marc
    ├── Lian
    └── Bonny
```

But when I export the tree to json and then import it back, the only node I seem to be able to reference is the root. So I can't do this kind of modification anymore because the variable names like `dan` or `marc` are not there, ie, I don't find a way to reference a node. Am I missing anything?

```
with open ('cajon/anytreeexample.json', 'r+', encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
    datos = importer.read(f)

print (datos)
```

This means that after importing the tree what you have is just a  root node

```
AnyNode(name='Udo')  # Udo is the root
```

From here you can get Udo's children, and the children's children like

```
marc, dan = udo.children
lian = marc.children
jet, jan, joe = dan.children
```

But they are not working as a node

```
print (lian.parent)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'parent'
```

And seems you cannot attach a children to them, which is my main purpose with this structure:

```
sonny = AnyNode("Sonny", parent = lian)
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'parent'
```

So my question is, is there a way to load the json saved tree into a proper anytree structure, where you can append new nodes?

Comment: You can reference the root, its children, its children's children, etc.

Comment: @Goyo I added some questions that arised after this idea. (I contemplated it, but didn't know how I would go to, say, a 5th level node, looks very complicated,I really don't know if it is

Comment: "But how would I do this without hard coding it ??" What do you mean? In order to bind a variable you need to assign the value `variable = value`, there is no other way. "Also it seems like some are not working as a node" `.children` returns a tuple, not a node. "And seems I also don't know how to add children" How about `sonny = Node("Sonny", parent = dan)`?

Comment: @Goyo that last line of code, I tried it before, doesn't work, precisely because after exporting you only get tuples not nodes. Also this tree has 6 nodes but I think I will have 600, first two levels fixed then adding as I find new nodes. There's got to be a different way than for each node instantiating it with node = Node ("Name", parent = parent) That's what I mean with hard coding.  My idea was that when I find something that belongs in a branch, I can just use a function that says "append this newnode under nodeX" . Then save it and next time I load the tree the newnode is there

Comment: `.children` always return a tuple of nodes, exporting has nothing to do with it. In order to append `newnode` under `nodeX`, assuming both `newnode` and `nodeX` are nodes, you just do `newnode.parent = nodeX`.

Comment: @gaurwraith take a look below, anytree actually behaves like you expected you just forgot a `,`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually did it the right way: you just forgot a `,`

```
from anytree import Node

udo = Node("Udo")
marc = Node("Marc", parent=udo)
Node("Lian", parent=marc)

lian, = marc.children # this is a tupel, even if its only one entry -> add ,
sonny = Node("Sonny", parent = lian)

print (lian.parent)
> Node('/Udo/Marc')

print (sonny)
> Node('/Udo/Marc/Lian/Sonny')
```

---

@How to find your nodes: You are looking for anytrees [`find_by_attr`](https://anytree.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/anytree.search.html#anytree.search.find_by_attr):

> Search for a single node with attribute name having value [...]

So after loading your tree with

```
with open ('cajon/anytreeexample.json', 'r+', encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
    datos = importer.read(f)
```

You can search for nodes by name:

```
udo = datos.find_by_attr("Udo") # should be the same as datos if udo was the root
```

And then add more like so:

```
Node("Sonny", parent = datos.find_by_attr("lian"))
```

Comment: Yes, indeed, the root of the problem was that, even single nodes are given in tuple form!