# Construct anytree from pandas DataFrame with multiple parents

Tags: python, pandas, anytree

I've got a huge DataFrame. This just an example. But you can see that "b" element has "a", "d", "k" parents.

```
data = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Parent","Child"], data=[["a","b"],["a","d"],["d","v"],["d","b"],["c","f"],["b","n"],["s","c"],["k","b"],["n","k"]])
```

[Read data from a pandas DataFrame and create a tree using anytree in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64084786/read-data-from-a-pandas-dataframe-and-create-a-tree-using-anytree-in-python)

In this solution tree is building, but parents overwriting.

How to build multiple parents tree?
P.S Maybe my array is bad.

Answer (score 1):

Because anytree is a pure tree library, it supports only a single parent per node.

If you want to assign multiple parents to a node, you're looking at a directed graph.
To work with such graphs in Python, try [networkx](https://networkx.org/)