# How to export a weighted edge list to a JSON tree?

Tags: json, pandas, networkx, echarts, edge-list

Given the following Pandas DataFrame (the original DataFrame has 200+ rows):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'child': ['Europe', 'France', 'Paris','North America', 'US', 'Canada'],
    'parent': ["", 'Europe', 'France',"", 'North America', 'North America'],
    'value': [746.4, 67.75, 2.16, 579,331.9, 38.25]
})
```

`df`

```
|---+---------------+---------------+--------|
|   | child         | parent        |  value |
|---+---------------+---------------+--------|
| 0 | Europe        |               | 746.40 |
| 1 | France        | Europe        |  67.75 |
| 2 | Paris         | France        |   2.16 |
| 3 | North America |               | 579.00 |
| 4 | US            | North America | 331.90 |
| 5 | Canada        | North America |  38.25 |
|---+---------------+---------------+--------|
```

I want to generate the following JSON tree:

```
  [
      {
      name: 'Europe',
      value: 746.4,
      children: [
          {
          name: 'France',
          value: 67.75,
          children: [
              {
              name: 'Paris',
              value: 2.16
              }
          ]
          }
      ]
      },
      {
      name: 'North America',
      value: 579,
      children: [
          {
          name: 'US',
          value: 331.9,
          },
          {
          name: 'Canada',
          value: 38.25
          }
      ]
      }
  ];
```

This tree will be used as an input for ECharts visualizations, like for example this [basic sunburst chart](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=sunburst-simple).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a library called [`bigtree`](https://github.com/kayjan/bigtree) which can do exactly what you are looking for.

```py
import json
import bigtree

# Set the parent values for children without parents to ROOT
df["parent"] = df["parent"].replace(r'^$', "ROOT", regex = True)

tree = bigtree.dataframe_to_tree_by_relation(df, "child", "parent")
# tree.show(all_attrs = True)

# Convert to dict and discard the ROOT key
tree_dict = bigtree.tree_to_nested_dict(tree, all_attrs = True)["children"]

# Convert the dict to the desired string format
print(json.dumps(tree_dict, indent = 2))
```

Also see: [Read data from a pandas DataFrame and create a tree using anytree in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64084786/read-data-from-a-pandas-dataframe-and-create-a-tree-using-anytree-in-python/77818696#77818696)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`networkx`](https://networkx.org/) package for this. First convert the dataframe to a graph:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='parent', target='child', edge_attr='value', create_using=nx.DiGraph)
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
```

This will result in a weighted graph:
[image]

Next, we get the graph as a JSON formatted tree:

```
from networkx.readwrite import json_graph

data = json_graph.tree_data(G, root='')
data = data['children']  # remove the root
```

This will look as follows:

```
[{'id': 'Europe',
  'children': [{'id': 'France', 'children': [{'id': 'Paris'}]}]},
 {'id': 'North America', 'children': [{'id': 'US'}, {'id': 'Canada'}]}]
```

Finally, post-process the JSON data by adding back the values and renaming 'id' to 'name'. Maybe there is a better way of doing this but the below works.

```
edge_values = nx.get_edge_attributes(G,'value')

def post_process_json(data, parent=''):
    print(data)
    data['name'] = data.pop('id')
    data['value'] = edge_values[(parent, data['name'])]
    if 'children' in data.keys():
        data['children'] = [post_process_json(child, parent=data['name']) for child in data['children']]
    return data

data = [post_process_json(d) for d in data]
```

Final result:

```
[{'children': [{'children': [{'name': 'Paris', 'value': 2.16}],
    'name': 'France',
    'value': 67.75}],
  'name': 'Europe',
  'value': 746.4},
 {'children': [{'name': 'US', 'value': 331.9},
   {'name': 'Canada', 'value': 38.25}],
  'name': 'North America',
  'value': 579.0}]
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm currently working out a solution with Networkx. There is built in function to generate JSON trees: https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/generated/networkx.readwrite.json_graph.tree_data.html that works quite well. I'm trying to find out how to add the `value` attribute.

Comment: @crocefisso: Yeah, I also don't know how to best add the attributes to the tree hence the ugly post-processing step in the answer here.

Comment: You can modify the original `tree_data` method and add before Line 80 https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/30ac7956569cb0c4f0787600f8537425d05c5dca/networkx/readwrite/json_graph/tree.py#L80 `data = G.get_edge_data(n, child);
if data is not None: d.update(**data);`

Answer (score 1):

You could first create the individual nodes as `{ name, value }` dicts, and key them by name. Then link them up:

```
result = []
d = { "": { "children": result } }
for child, value in zip(df["child"], df["value"]):
    d[child] = { "name": child, "value": value }
for child, parent in zip(df["child"], df["parent"]):
    if "children" not in d[parent]:
        d[parent]["children"] = []
    d[parent]["children"].append(d[child])
```

For the example, `result` would be:

```
[{
    'name': 'Europe', 
    'value': 746.4, 
    'children': [{
        'name': 'France', 
        'value': 67.75, 
        'children': [{
            'name': 'Paris', 
            'value': 2.16
        }]
    }]
}, {
    'name': 'North America', 
    'value': 579.0, 
    'children': [{
        'name': 'US', 
        'value': 331.9
    }, {
        'name': 'Canada', 
        'value': 38.25
    }]
}]
```